# Running Java jar file with included external tools

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, external

In eclipse I have a java project that runs an external program (a .exe) from the main method. This program is in a folder ext under the rot of the project on the same level as the source folder. Now when I run this program from Eclipse it works Like a charm. But when I export a jar file, it does not. I end up with a jar file that does contain the ext folder, but I still get a FileNotFoundException.
I did think of using getClass.getResource('path'), but I can't use this from the static main method.

Any ideas?

Comment: yields "The method getResource(String) is undefined for the type ClassName"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around the static issue, you can use ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource('path')

This may or may not work depending on how you are launching your .exe (it doesn't really have a file path now, since it is inside the .jar, and I'm guessing it won't) - having a .exe inside a .jar seems odd to me.  Why not leave it outside the .jar, and specify its location with a configuration parameter?  This would make much more sense.

Comment: Yes, odd it is, but I really want a single runnable jar file in this case.

Comment: I get "The method getClassLoader() is undefined for the type System"

Comment: try ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource('path')

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Foo.class.getResource("...");
```

Comment: Replace `Foo` with your class name

Comment: Then it will fail, because it is run from a static method